# Which signature algorithm can handle RSA keys?

Tags: java, digital-signature

I've developed an Java RMI Application. I have already implemented hybrid encryption for all communication between the different clients and servers. For my asymmetric keys I use RSA. Now I'm trying to implement signatures, using the [SignedObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SignedObject.html) class. As a third parameter when creating a new SignedObject, I have to pass a signature algorithm. My question is which signature algorithm is compatible to work with my already implemented RSA keys?

Currently I'm using the default signature algorithm DSA, as mentioned in the documentation. However, when running the application I encounter the following error:

```
TweetClient exception (publish): java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl
java.security.InvalidKeyException: No installed provider supports this key: sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.chooseProvider(Signature.java:1138)
    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign(Signature.java:1179)
    at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:530)
    at java.security.SignedObject.sign(SignedObject.java:240)
    at java.security.SignedObject.<init>(SignedObject.java:160)
    at be.vub.parallellism.solutions.encryption.EncryptionUnit.encryptWithSecretKey(EncryptionUnit.java:80)
    at be.vub.parallellism.solutions.TweetClient.publish(TweetClient.java:137)
    at be.vub.parallellism.solutions.TweetClient.access$000(TweetClient.java:25)
    at be.vub.parallellism.solutions.TweetClient$1.run(TweetClient.java:126)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, "SHA256withRSA" can be used for RSA keys with a size of 256 bytes.